# Ruby on Rails Tutorial - Ch 7 CSS issues

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im working my way through Michael Hartls Ruby on Rails tutorial and have run into a snag in while trying to get my style to match that of the tutorial. For whatever reason the changes that should be applied to the text in h1 under sidebar aren't going through and I cant find where the error in my code is.

This is his styling:
[image: This is his styling]

And this is mine:
[image: and this is mine]

This is the code in question.

```css
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";

/* mixins, variables, etc. */

$gray-medium-light: #eaeaea;

@mixin box_sizing {
  -moz-box-sizing:    border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing:         border-box;
}

/* universal */

body {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

section {
  overflow: auto;
}

textarea {
  resize: vertical;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
  h1 {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}

/* typography */

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  line-height: 1;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: $gray-light;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  line-height: 1.7em;
}


/* header */

#logo {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  padding-top: 9px;
  font-weight: bold;
  &:hover {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}

/* footer */

footer {
  margin-top: 45px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid $gray-medium-light;
  color: $gray-light;
  a {
    color: $gray;
    &:hover {
      color: $gray-darker;
    }
  }
  small {
    float: left;
  }
  ul {
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    li {
      float: left;
      margin-left: 15px;
    }
  }
}

  /* miscellaneous */

.debug_dump {
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 45px;
  @include box_sizing;
  }

  /* sidebar */

aside {
  section.user_info {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  section {
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin-top: 20px;
    &:first-child {
      border: 0;
      padding-top: 0;
    }
    span {
      display: block;
      margin-bottom: 3px;
      line-height: 1;
    }
    h1 {
      font-size: 1.4em;
      text-align: left;
      letter-spacing: -1px;
      margin-bottom: 3px;
      margin-top: 0px;
    }
  }
}


.gravatar {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.gravatar_edit {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

Comment: This seems pretty similar to me. And I can't see any sidebar. Can you quote the bit of text that look different to you?

Comment: the "Example user" title is supposed to be on the left hand side of the page and a bit smaller.

I think the h1 block of code in the sidebar block at the bottom is supposed to do this but I cant get it to work.

Comment: For now I think your h1 tag inherit the h1 css bit : h1 { font-size: 3em; letter-spacing: -2px; margin-bottom: 30px; text-align: center; }. Are you sure your html is matching the css for sidebar?

Comment: Yeah thats whats styling it at the moment. If I change that bit of code to to exclude the centering styling it fixes it a bit but I thought the section in the sidebar block would override the above code?

Comment: Sure this is what it should do, if your html does have the right tags <aside> etc.. I am no expert in this field, but you should check the html, not only the css..

Comment: Thats where the error was! Thanks!!

Comment: Cool. Regarding Michael Hartl tutorial, you have done a fair bit reaching chapter 7. I actually found it very difficult, especially the testing bits with Rspec. I found the Rubyonrails.org "getting started" guide much easier and useful for the begginer. Don't hesitate to have a look at it too

Comment: I'll be sure to check it out. Thanks!

Comment: @J.kay Please show us your custom.css.scss file? and your github repo?